# Viewing Ubuntu command line in the web browser

Tags: command-line, networking, server

I have an Ubuntu server running Netatalk and flex media server. I was just thinking that if I need to access the Ubuntu terminal from a machine like Windows is there a way I can simply enter my server's ip address and see my server's terminal. Both the machines are on the same network. ssh is one way. But can I see my server's terminal on a web browser or is it is impossible?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but you'd need a web server set up to serve an SSH session through a webpage using something like **ShellInABox**: https://github.com/shellinabox/shellinabox

That type of setup seems unnecessarily complicated to me, and probably presents new security holes that you wouldn't otherwise have on your server.

A much easier way to see your server's terminal would be to use a Windows program like **PuTTY**: http://www.putty.org/ or even the Google Chrome extension **Secure Shell**: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/secure-shell/pnhechapfaindjhompbnflcldabbghjo which both use your server's standard SSH software.